How to do Boolean operation on instance pairs with geometry nodes
I am new to this so I don't fully get everything. I want to place cylinders on a curve by using instances on points, and then on the same curve, place another set of cylinders that are smaller in size, and then do a boolean operation (difference) on those cylinders in pairs, so the cylinder on the index 1 should only do a difference operation with the cylinder on the other set at index 1. Whatever I tried, it seems that the cylinders from different indexes overlap.
This is what I have done so far:

And it looks like this:

So somehow, the inner cylinder of one index, merges with the inner cylinder of the next index and they subtract eachother somehow? I don't get it :(


You need to use a repeat zone to separate boolean operations. Or move hulls away so that they don't collide.

@MarkusvonBroady I don't know how to use repeat zones for this :(

Is it what you are trying to achieve ? https://i.sstatic.net/zNgioQ5n.png

@StefLAncien, it seems like it, but I am not quite sure, because now it seems that there is red both on the inner side of the discs, and on top. This means that it also subtracts from the neighbor discs as well, right?

Can you model manually what you want to achieve? I understand you need geonodes for parametric control, but once you model manually the desired topology, the question becomes much more clear. BTW, as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem , would you be satisfied with a solution that doesn't involve boolean at all?

(Blender 4.2.4)

To restrict boolean operations to pairs of instanced objects, the dark pink nodes are offsetting pairs to avoid overlap between pairs before the Mesh Boolean node, based on instance Index. Then the dark green nodes are restoring original positions after the Mesh Boolean node, based on mesh island Index.
Resources:
(Blender 4.2.4+)

Thank you! That seems to do the trick!
